# Issues with pytz 2019.1, Django 2.2?

Tags: django, virtualenv, pytz

I noticed that my Django-server crashes when I update **pytz==2018.7** to **pytz==2019.1**. The Pytz library is in charge for all Timezone calculations.  I ask myself if something changed and where I can find a changelog?
I did not change anything time related in my Django project and when I go back to **pytz==2018.7** everything works fine.
I am using Django 2.2 with virtualenv, here is my list

```
Python==3.7.2
Django 2.2
Virtualenv==16.5.0 
Django==2.2
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.3
djangorestframework==3.9.2
Pillow==6.0.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pytz==2018.7
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

**Settings.py**

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True
<…>
```

**latest crash with pytz==2019.1 update**

```
(env2) D:\coding\Webprojects\phone>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\coding\appz\python 3_7_2_64bit\Lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "d:\coding\appz\python 3_7_2_64bit\Lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 80, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django.test.client import encode_multipart
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.test import signals
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 149, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 94, in acquire
_frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 2019111034216
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\coding\Webprojects\phone\phone\urls.py", line 27, in <module>
    path('data/', include('dataout.urls', namespace='data_home')),
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\coding\Webprojects\phone\dataout\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\urlpatterns.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.test.signals import setting_changed
  File "D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\test\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'django.test.client' (D:\coding\virtual_env\env2\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py)
```